# How can I calculate the duration of a given variable in a data set?

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
### Here I am preparing my colulm of Time in the desired format

hours <-
  c("10:44:40", "10:45:00", "10:45:30", "10:45:38", "10:45:50")
horas_preparadas <- as.POSIXct(hours, format = "%H:%M:%S")
formatted_time <- format(horas_preparadas, format = "%H:%M:%S")

### Here I am creating my data frame

prueba <-
  data.frame(
    Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    Obs = as.factor(c("Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike")),
    Behavior = c(
      "Auto-grooming",
      "Self-Scratch",
      "Grunt",
      "Auto-grooming",
      "Self-Scratch"
    ),
    Time = formatted_time
  )
```

```
  Id  Obs      Behavior     Time
1  1 Mike Auto-grooming 10:44:40
2  1 Mike  Self-Scratch 10:45:00
3  1 Mike         Grunt 10:45:30
4  1 Mike Auto-grooming 10:45:38
5  1 Mike  Self-Scratch 10:45:50
```

How long does the "Auto-grooming" behaviour in the "Behaviour" column last in total?

Its duration depends on the beginning of the next stated behavior. For instance, the first "Auto-grooming", which begins at 10:44:40, lasts 20 seconds, as the next behavior "Self-scratch", begins at 10:45:00.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `horas_preparadas` rather than `formatted_time` to make this easier. When you use `format()` you don't really gain anything but you do lose the time structure.

One way to do what you want would be this:

```
library(tidyverse)

prueba <-
  data.frame(
    Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    Obs = as.factor(c("Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike")),
    Behavior = c("Auto-grooming", "Self-Scratch", "Grunt",
              "Auto-grooming","Self-Scratch"),
    Time = horas_preparadas
  )

prueba |>
  mutate(duration = lead(Time) - Time)
```

```
  Id  Obs      Behavior                Time duration
1  1 Mike Auto-grooming 2023-10-21 10:44:40  20 secs
2  1 Mike  Self-Scratch 2023-10-21 10:45:00  30 secs
3  1 Mike         Grunt 2023-10-21 10:45:30   8 secs
4  1 Mike Auto-grooming 2023-10-21 10:45:38  12 secs
5  1 Mike  Self-Scratch 2023-10-21 10:45:50  NA secs
```

Once you have this, I think you want to group by `Behavior` and find the aggregate duration. One way to do that would be:

```
prueba |>
  mutate(duration = lead(Time) - Time) |>
  group_by(Behavior) |>
  summarise(duration = sum(duration, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
  Behavior      duration
  <chr>         <drtn>  
1 Auto-grooming 32 secs 
2 Grunt          8 secs 
3 Self-Scratch  30 secs
```

Self-Scratch does not have a well-defined duration here since we don't know when it ends in the last row. You can ignore this issue with `na.rm = TRUE` in the `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `diff` and `ave` for group-wise operations. You can use shorthand `"%T"` instead of `"%H:%M:%S"` in `as.POSIXct`. `as.numeric` gives seconds that have passed since Jan 1, 1970, with which you can easily calculate the time `diff`erences.

```
> transform(dat, secs=ave(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Time, format="%T")), Id,
+                         FUN=\(x) diff(c(x, NA))))
  Id  Obs      Behavior     Time secs
1  1 Mike Auto-grooming 10:44:40   20
2  1 Mike  Self-Scratch 10:45:00   30
3  1 Mike         Grunt 10:45:30    8
4  1 Mike Auto-grooming 10:45:38   12
5  1 Mike  Self-Scratch 10:45:50   NA
6  2  Ana  Auto-groomin 11:45:36  614
7  2  Ana  Self-Scratch 11:55:50  600
8  2  Ana         Grunt 12:05:50   NA
```

Or using `data.table`

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(dat)[, secs := diff(c(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Time, format="%T")), NA)), by=Id]
> dat
   Id  Obs      Behavior     Time secs
1:  1 Mike Auto-grooming 10:44:40   20
2:  1 Mike  Self-Scratch 10:45:00   30
3:  1 Mike         Grunt 10:45:30    8
4:  1 Mike Auto-grooming 10:45:38   12
5:  1 Mike  Self-Scratch 10:45:50   NA
6:  2  Ana  Auto-groomin 11:45:36  614
7:  2  Ana  Self-Scratch 11:55:50  600
8:  2  Ana         Grunt 12:05:50   NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Obs = c("Mike", 
"Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Ana", "Ana", "Ana"), Behavior = c("Auto-grooming", 
"Self-Scratch", "Grunt", "Auto-grooming", "Self-Scratch", "Auto-groomin", 
"Self-Scratch", "Grunt"), Time = c("10:44:40", "10:45:00", "10:45:30", 
"10:45:38", "10:45:50", "11:45:36", "11:55:50", "12:05:50")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```